# What does "spacco" mean in the lyrics of "Stivali e colbacco"?

Tags: word-meaning, colloquial

Here's an excerpt from Adriano Celentano's song *Stivali e colbacco*:

> Sei alta, sei bionda
> Sei proprio uno spacco
> Con quegli stivali
> E quel nero colbacco

I've been trying to figure out the exact meaning of *sei uno spacco*.

The main meaning of "slit, crack" seems to be, how shall I put it, a dubious compliment for a girl.

I thought it was maybe about a slit on a skirt, but I don't see how it would make any sense either.

Wiktionary mentions this meaning of *spaccare*: "(intransitive, slang) to rock, to be very skillful; to excel". It looks like a good fit, but I couldn't find the use of the noun *spacco* in this meaning anywhere except the song.

Someone on a Russian translators' forum [claims](http://www.trworkshop.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=34646) that it's the song author's invention to replace *sei uno schianto* which doesn't rhyme.

So what is the meaning of *spacco* in the context of this song and is this meaning idiomatic?

Comment: The Russian traslators' Forum is right. *Sei uno spacco* here means 'you are really cool, you are gorgeosu' (from 'spaccare', slang,  quoted by Wikitionary). Nothing to do with skirts and clothes. I don't know if it is used somewhere in Italy, but I think that it is an invention of Celentano to rhyme. I think that many Italians would understand the meaning of this phrase, even if they haven't heard it before.

Comment: @BakerStreet:  Could it be a sexual reference, as it seems to be suggested [here](https://books.google.es/books?hl=it&id=uxh9DwAAQBAJ&q=spacco#v=snippet&q=spacco&f=false)?

Comment: No, not in the sense suggested in your link. It means simply 'sei uno schianto'.

Comment: @BakerStreet: could you please make it into an answer?

Comment: Of course, I wrote a comment because, if souces and quotations are needed, I havent' them, **I** am the source... :-) But I think it is impossible to have sources and quotations about this matter.

Comment: @BakerStreet: A quanto pare, su questo [libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=GM2TEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT41&dq=%22Forme+della+comunicazione+giovanile%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwisztHwzvD_AhXb7rsIHZbCAoEQ6AF6BAgJEAE#v=onepage&q=spaccare&f=false) si trova qualcosa su "spaccare" nel senso che hai menzionato.

Comment: Yes, about *spaccare*, but not about *spacco* in the sense of Celentano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Russian translators' Forum is right.

*Sei uno spacco*, here, means *you are really cool, you are gorgeous* (from *spaccare*, slang, quoted by Wikitionary), *sei uno schianto*.

Nothing to do with skirts and clothes.

I don't know if it is used somewhere in Italy, maybe, but  it is likely that it is an invention of Celentano to rhyme.

I think, however,  that many Italians would understand the meaning of this phrase, even if they haven't heard it before.

Comment: However, I'm not sure if the slang sense of "spaccare" you are referring to was already in use when this song was written (around 1970 according to Italian Wikipedia). In the book I have previously linked you can read:

Comment: "Decisamente inferiori sono le occorrenze della terza parola, ossia *spaccare* (11) 'provocare entusiasmo', 'convincere', 'andare forte' (specie con riferimento a un esibizione canora), un verbo che in realtà non è nato in questi ultimi ultimi anni; si configura come un giovanilismo di lunga durata, presente già nel primo decennio del 2000 (su Twitter una prima attestazione è del 2007, così anche su Google Libri in un libro di Raffaele Sedda, intitolato *Maria Teresa Sedda: diario condiviso*) e oggetto di riflessione anche da parte della stampa nel 2015".

Comment: Io non sono tanto giovane, e anche molto tempo fa *spaccare* nel senso citato mi sarebbe suonato familiare. Ma comunque non è che abbia troppa importanza da dove l'abbia preso Celentano, non credo che sia andato per il sottile linguisticamente, l'ha inventato e basta, probabilmente, per 'licenza poetica'. Celentano è un cantante popolare, si è probabilmente inventato, per qualche assonanza,  perché gli faceva comodo, un termine che suona come slang,  comprensibile comunque al pubblico.

Comment: Sì, sì, molto probabilmente è stato così. A proposito, a quanto pare, il testo non è di Celentano: http://discografia.dds.it/scheda_titolo.php?idt=10561.

Comment: Ah grazie dell'informazione. Il fatto è che quelli che scrivono canzoni si inventano di tutto di sana pianta, anche giustamente, come per la poesia, non so  se hai presente i testi di Battisti, ad esempio, quindi non è che sempre li si possa ricondurre alla lingua standard, anche slang o dialettale.

Comment: È comune per gli autori italiani inventare nuove parole ed espressioni proprio così? Non riesco a ricordarmi nessun autore né russo né inglese che abbia inventato dal nulla una nuova espressione solo per fare rima (forse tranne che per le canzoni "novelty", non so come si dice in italiano)

Comment: Ma sì, credo che sia comune, non necessariamente per fare rima, ma è comune, ma anche in poesia, trattare il testo secondo le proprie esigenze. Non so in altre lingue, ma immagino che anche là si concedano licenze poetiche.

Comment: @Quassnoi:   It's not about inventing a word: you can find this word on a dictionary. It's about constructing a metaphor. Consider symbolism, for instance.